# Use inputs in AngularJS Material bottom-sheet

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, cordova, material-design

## The problem

I'm designing a Cordova hybrid app using the (very) new **[AngularJS Material Design dependency](https://material.angularjs.org/)**.

I have a log in form in a bottom sheet called via `$mdBottomSheet` service.  Example below:

```
$scope.showLogin = function ($event) {
  $mdBottomSheet.show({
    templateUrl: 'views/login/login.html',
    controller: 'loginCtrl'
  })
};
```

The contents of `views/login/login.html` are:

```
<md-bottom-sheet ng-controller="loginCtrl" layout="column">
  <form name="signInForm" ng-submit="submitPassword()">
    <md-list>
      <md-item>
        <md-progress-circular md-mode="indeterminate" ng-show="loading"></md-progress-circular>
      </md-item>
      <md-item>
        <md-text-float label="Email address" ng-model="username" required>
        </md-text-float>
      </md-item>
      <md-item>
        <md-text-float type="password" label="Password" ng-model="password" required>
        </md-text-float>
      </md-item>
      <md-item>
        <md-button class="md-primary md-raised submit" type="submit">Sign in</md-button>
      </md-item>
    </md-list>
  </form>
</md-bottom-sheet>
```

Everything runs and displays just fine.

**HOWEVER!** when I go to click on the input, the focus is never given to the input, and instead the `md-bottom-sheet` element is dragged back and forth.  Clicking on the button (when not disabled) fires just fine, but the click on the input to give it focus is never recognized.

---

## Things I've tried

1. Adding `ng-click="return false"`, 'ng-click="$event.preventDefault()"`
2. Adding a `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 80px, 0) !important;` rule to the CSS, as that's the default state of the property which is being altered on drag.
3. Adding `angular.element('md-bottom-sheet').on('click', function() { return false; });` to an `ng-init` block.
4. Doing the same as above (using jQuery to try to ham-hand this) on the `dragstart` event.

---

## The question

How can I use an input in a bottom sheet with material design, given I've tried every workaround that I know to get this to work for touch?

---

<sub>**Caveats**</sub>

<sub>1. I would love to offer a live example for this, but I can't find a CDN source for [angular/material](https://github.com/angular/material)</sub>

<sub>2. This only happens on a mobile device, no idea if it will happen on a mobile website as I've only tested it in a Cordova hybrid app</sub>

<sub>3. There are no examples of this I've found via search, so I can't even point you to a resource that might emulate the problem.</sub>

<sub>4. Basically, this is going to be very hard to reproduce.</sub>

---

## Update

One possible fix I've identified:

The following block in the `function BottomSheet(element)` "class" for the provider has the following:

```
function onTouchStart(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  /* do the rest of the code */
}
```

Changing that `e.preventDefault()` to the following **does allow normal input behavior**, but requires that I fork their repo.

```
if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'input')
  e.preventDefault()
```

**Is there a solution that doesn't require me to fork this for such a minor change?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were near the solution. You had to use `stopPropagation()` instead of `preventDefault()`. Here is the simple approach:

**Directive (.coffee)**

```
angular.module('Expedite').directive 'stopEvent', ->
  restrict: 'A'
  link: (scope, element, attr) ->
    element.bind attr.stopEvent, (e) ->
      e.stopPropagation()
```

**View (.slim)**

```
input ng-model="user.email" stop-event='touchstart'
```

This way you will not have to fork material repo.

Comment: For future readers, the directive does work, but it doesn't matter if it's `preventDefault` or `stopPropagation`.

Answer (score 1):

So I'm running into exactly the same issue. The code above works for pre 0.6.1 - though doesn't work so well afterwards.

I have however found that moving that `e.preventDefault()` (minus the `if()` logic) down to the `onTouchMove(e)` function, seems to fix all scroll glitches (atleast that I can see) - and still allows inputs to function normally.

Agree, it would be super if the ng-material guys could incorporate something like this into the repo to make $mdBottomSheet implementation more flexible.

Comment: Good to know.  For what it's worth, the guys developing Angular Material basically shot this down as bottom sheets aren't ever supposed to have inputs according to spec.